# Which "Wonders of the World" book does Malcolm X refer to in his autobiography?

Tags: book, civil-rights

In the Autobiography of Malcolm X, he references reading a book called "Wonders of the World". He lists no author or publisher. A Google search for "Wonders of the World book" brings up a large number of varying books. What book or set of books was Malcolm X referencing in his book?

Original excerpt from the Autobiography of Malcolm X:

> I can remember accurately the very first set of books that really impressed me. I have since bought that set of books and I have it at home for my children to read as they grow up. It's called Wonders of the World. It's full of pictures of archeological finds, statues that depict, usually, non-European people.

Comment: I think the title of the book was "Wonders of the World". There are multiple books of that kind (e.g. [Wonders of the World](https://www.amazon.com/Wonders-World-Sir-Philip-Gibbs/dp/B001P42DJ6), which was published at approximately the right age - the copy he bought for his children is probably later).

Comment: "Set of books" makes me think he's talking about the World Book Encyclopedia, which I remember had a "Wonders of the World" volume.